# How do I determine the value of a dropdown?

Tags: python, cgi

This is the Html form:

```
<form action='use.py'>
<div><input type='text' name='etc'></div>           
<p><input type='submit' value='etc!'></p>
</form>
```

And this is the python for it

```
 colour = form["colour"].value
```

The top html form is a text box that users can type something in.

If I were to have a drop down box / radio button form like this:

```
<form action='etc.py'>

    <p>List Type:</p>
    <div><input type='radio' name='status' value='bulleted' checked>
        Bulleted
    </div>
    <div><input type='radio' name='status' value='numbered'>
        Numbered
    </div>

    <p>Text style:</p>
    <div><input type='checkbox' name='bold'>
        <b>Bold</b>
    </div>
    <div><input type='checkbox' name='italic'>
        <i>Italic</i>
    </div>

    <p>Movies to display:</p>
    <div>
        <select name='type'>
            <option>Only numbers</option>
            <option>Only names</option>
        </select>
    </div>    

    <p><input type='submit' value='Display'></p>
</form>
```

How would I write my python? Like this?

```
only_numbers = form["Only numbers"].value
```

Comment: We'll probably need more information. What python framework are you using. What's the desired behavior?

Comment: I want to make it that if the option was choosen "Only Numbers" that only numbers appear from a saved .data file. And if "Only names" is chosen, then only the names appear from a saved .data file.

Comment: @AjEntity: Still, Python by itself won't make this work. You need to have some kind of web framework to facilitate serving pages, processing forms etc.

Comment: @che yea, I have that. A server that can handle server side scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Python CGI script, but most Python frameworks are built upon WSGI and have a concept of request/response objects. For example, in Django the value would be available at `request.POST['fieldname']`.

Using the python CGI module, it is like:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# for multiple elements with same name or elements with multiple values
a_list = form.getlist("multiple_select_input")
# For single value elements
if "single_value_input" in form:
    x = form["single_value_input"].value
else:
    x = "default value"
# or
x = form.getvalue("single_value_input", "default value")
```